# Is it correct to train and validate the model on F1-score metrics?

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation, overfitting, train

I am trying to do experiments on multiple data sets. Some are more imbalanced than others.
Now, in order to assure fair reporting, we compute [F1-Score](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/f-score) on test data. In most machine learning models, we train and validate the model via accuracy measure metric.
However, this time, I decided to train and validate the model on an F1-score metric measure.
Technically, there should be no problems, in my opinion.
However, I am wondering if this is the correct approach to go.

Second, when I use this method (training, validation on F1-score), I receive a higher loss error and a lower F1-score on training data than on validation data.
I'm not sure why.